# What is the official term for a gas / petrol station for planes?

Tags: terminology, refueling

I'm talking specifically about small airports where they don't have the fancy equipment and they actually have to go to a specific place to refuel for example cars go to gas station / petrol station so:

Is there an official term for a fuel station specific to planes?

Comment: In some places, it's simply [the Kwik Stop](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Q_AlGfAAfJ8/UFJeUrhaATI/AAAAAAAAHDg/QhgPYmeYvR0/s1600/5.jpg)

Comment: Official? Per whose office?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At airport with a standalone self-serve facility, it's a Self Serve Fuel(ing) Station.  If it's a business selling fuel in addition to other services, that is a Fixed Base Operator, or FBO.

Answer (score 12):

On a small GA airfield we just refer to them as "The pumps". As in my typical radio conversation goes like this

> [Airfield] [service], G-ABCD request taxi to pumps.

Answer (score 7):

They’re referred to as self service fuel pumps, or fuel terminals.  I don’t know if anybody has officially named the but pilots call them that.

Answer (score 6):

Our fuel pumps are on the west side of the airport and most people just request: “Taxi to west-side fuel.”